# Detect whether the compiler has full C++11 support from Rcpp

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I am building a package using `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`, and when I install it on one of my machines I get the following compiler warnings from functions which use `RcppArmadillo`:

> WARNING: your C++ compiler is in C++11 mode, but it has incomplete
>   support for C++11 features; if something breaks, you get to keep all
>   the pieces

As far as I can tell, this doesn't break any of my code, however it would be nice to turn off these warnings if possible.

Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947365/how-to-disable-c11-in-armadillo) I know I can disable C++11 support for Armadillo by adding the following macro before I include the RcppArmadillo header file:

```cpp
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11
```

Which is just a shorthand for:

```cpp
#if defined(ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11)
  #undef ARMA_USE_CXX11
  #undef ARMA_USE_CXX11_RNG
#endif
```

What I'd like to be able to do is detect whether the compiler has full support for C++11 extensions or not, and `#undef` the appropriate macros only if the machines compiler doesn't support full C++11 extensions.

According to the R extensions manual, this should be stored in `CXX1XSTD`, so I want to do something like:

```
#if CXX1XSTD == "-std=c++0x"
  #undef ARMA_USE_CXX11
  #undef ARMA_USE_CXX11_RNG
#endif
```

However `CXX1XSTD` isn't a predefined macro in Rcpp or C++, so I that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly:

1. The first warning is from Armadillo. Conrad works hard to keep his code compliant; he chose to put this warning in. You did *not say which compiler version you used* so I can't comment further.
2. The rest of your post is a little confused.  There are actual test macros for compilers and versions -- a well known source is [this one at sf.net](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) -- and we try out best to reflect that in our sources.
3. In short, g++ 4.8 or later (as on Linux) and clang 3.4 or 3.5 (as on Linux and OS X) are good enough.
4. Windows and its g++ 4.6.* has issues.  That latter one is the compiler we are given by Rtools and there is little we can do.
5. `CXX1XSTD` is defined by R 3.1.0 or later.  R tests the compiler during *its* compile / build cycle and remember, so when as you for a C++11 etc compliant compiler R knows whether to give you c++0x or c++11. In essence, you are thinking here that you know better; I think you may be wrong in that belief. But hey, if there is something we can do better than we currently do in the Rcpp / RcppArmadillo headers then let us know.
6. I didn't see where you said why you turned C++11 on. Are you actually using C++11 or later features? Because if you don't then the whole issue is moot.  But if you do then you need to be careful. Many R installations will have old compilers (Windows, older RHEL, ...).
7. I suspect you'd get overall better respones if you posted on rcpp-devel.